# How to get total row of ngFor loop in html?

Tags: html, angular, web, angular9

How can i get the total number of ngfor loop and then display it in

on above?

```
            <p>Total row: "I need to display the number of row here"</p>
           
            <table class="table" >
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>

                <tr *ngFor="let l of list">
                    <td>{{l.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{l.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

list.length will give the total number of rows to be displayed

```
<p>Total row: "I need to display the number of row here" {{list.length}}</p>
           
            <table class="table" >
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>

                <tr *ngFor="let l of list">
                    <td>{{l.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{l.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

the list is an array, so you can use length property.

```
<p>Total row: {{list.length}}</p>
           
<table class="table" >
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let l of list">
        <td>{{l.id}}</td>
        <td>{{l.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```